# How can i avoid to generation of an empty report document

Tags: report, birt

I don't want to generate empty report document(rptdesign) in java. Means some times my report is not having data then also it generates empty report which i don't want. Previously it was generating table heading also but that is solved by using Total.count(). 
   Right now i don't want generate empty report at all. If result-set is null then it should not generate report document.Please help me.
   **Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

How are you managing generating your report? Are you starting generating the report from the code?
If yes, then your code should check conditions whether to generate the report or not. It is outside report control.

Comment: yes report would be controlled by checking conditions in code. but is it possible to control its execution by Birt report.

Comment: Thanks for replying Kazik1616, Yes i am generating report by code itself. But is it right way to check condition in code because we have to query to db. And in report again we have to do the same.

Comment: hi reetika, we can check table condition in report itself by using Total.count() function of table, it will return number of fetched rows if no then it will return 0.